# Looking for a simple method to find the shortest path with Shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, route

I am having shapefiles for a particular map location, the shapefile consists of points and polylines. Now I want to find the shortest path between the points. What is perfect and simple method to find shortest path.

Comment: You have not specified restrictions (do you want obstacle avoidance? Do you want smooth turns? etc. etc.) Look up Delaunay triangulations/Voronoi diagrams, A* algorithm and its derivatives. One of the approaches is based on transforming the shapefile into a graph and running a modification of A* on it.

Comment: You will need pgrouting/postgis to do this in QGIS see Devdatta Tengshe's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned what tool you are working in, here goes my suggestion.

I have just started my work on the similar task and Network Analyst (ArcGIS) gives you good results in what you are looking for. Try this out.
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Network_Analyst_Tutorial

You can also load your shapefile to google earth pro and carry out your task.

Comment: I am using QuantumGiS and Postgresql till now

Comment: Google Earth Pro is Simple work, Thanks for referring this , Thank you once again ..

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a OpenSource Solution, you need to look at pgRouting.

You can [upload](http://pgrouting.org/docs/howto/shapefiles.html) your shapefiles in to postgis, and then run pgrouting on it.

To get started with pgRouting, I would suggest this [workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/).

Answer (score 2):

QGIS 2.0 contains all the functionality necessary to calculate shortest paths. The API is documented here: http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html

I've created a Processing script for the use case of routing between consecutive points: http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/19/a-routing-script-for-the-processing-toolbox/

[image]